# Installed Perl Modules will wiped out if VM Hardware Upgrade happens

Tags: perl, redhat

My VM version is:`Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6` and Perl version is `This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi`.

Since I had to execute some Perl scripts which uses modules such as `Time::Piece`, `Time::Seconds` my VM constantly throwing an error message the modules haven't been installed.
Error Message is:

```
$ perl -MTime::Piece -e 1
Can't locate Time/Piece.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .).
```

So as mentioned in the [Doc](https://perlhacks.com/2012/08/a-cautionary-tale/) I executed the command `sudo yum install perl-core` which resolved my issue of module dependency in the VM.

Now my question is, if suppose virtual machine upgrade to the latest hardware version (for example, `RHEL 6` to `RHEL 7`) will the module been installed using `perl-core` will be wiped out.

This question is more related to VM, so including `Linux` tag too.

Comment: According to [`corelist`](https://metacpan.org/pod/corelist) : *"Time::Piece was first released with perl v5.9.5"* so it is strange that you needed to install it

Comment: According to  [Does Red Hat support upgrades between major versions of Red Hat Enterprise Linux?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/21964), *"Red Hat currently supports only upgrades from Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 to Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 for specific/targeted use cases only."*

Comment: You can check [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/637583) if you can upgrade from RHEL 6 to RHEL 7, if not I guess you need to reinstall `perl-core` in fresh installation

Answer (score 5):

For a VM, you are better off to create a new instance of RHEL in a new VM in the latest version than to attempt an upgrade, and you can load Perl-Core at install if necessary.

Perl is the least of your worries when migrating. The sweet thing about VMs is that it's easy to try it and see what issues you'll encounter.

Read the migration docs from RedHat.  There are significant changes between 6 and 7, and it's worth your time.

Comment: this.  always treat VMs as disposable and keep track _outside_ the vm of how it is set up; doesn't have to be ansible/chef/puppet/whatever, even just a bash script.  the key is "disposable"; you should be able to throw away your VM and easily build a new one that just works.  then your upgrade worries are limited to figuring out what configuration changes you need, and making sure your actual code works with new versions of everything it uses

Comment: Useful answer @Curt. But I was thinking whether need to execute the `perl-core` to have the Perl modules to be install again.

Comment: I wish I could give more votes to @ysth's comment. If it were an answer, I guess I could vote twice. :)